# Como configurar github no ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

Agora que terminei meu projeto final em `C` e entreguei no fim desse primeiro semestre.

Estou tentando **configurar e postar meu projeto no github**.

Segui uma vídeo aula e consegui `configurar` um `repositório` no meu notebook. **Porém não consigo subir o arquivo para a mesma pasta**.

Antes disso, *sem seguir vídeo aula*, eu já tinha criado um `repositório`, mas só no site, **sem pasta** no meu notebook.

**Agora, meu github tem dois repositórios e nenhum projeto.**

Um chamado `Linguagem-C`, onde de inicio eu iria apenas postar meus programas em C. E um chamado `projetosfinaisfaculdade`, onde eu iria postar todos os projetos de final de semestre da faculdade. Agora, nem apagar esses eu consigo.

já tentei seguir vários tutoriais mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguém poderia me dizer como configurar o github no ubuntu?

No meu caso, eu queria apagar esses dois que tenho primeiro e depois configurar apenas um master da maneira correta e colocar todos os projetos dentro de uma pasta só.

Se alguém precisar ver os repositórios no meu perfil, está aqui:
https://github.com/marciellioliveira

Desde já agradeço. ;)

Comment: Para deletar um repositório, acesse a página principal dele, vá em direção ao botão `Settings`, ao final da página carregada, haverá a opção `Delete this repository`. Ele pedirá que você informe o nome do repositório para confirmar a exclusão.

Comment: Um bom tutorial para `git` que usei para aprender foi este: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html

Comment: @JoãoIora Seguindo esses passos consegui deletar os dois. Esse link que me passou parece bem completo, vou começar a ler agora. Obrigada. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo os seguintes passos, fica bem fácil de criar e comitar arquivos em um repositório remoto.

Criando a pasta do projeto, entre nela pela linha de comando, digite `git init` para o git reconhecer sua pasta como a de um repositório.

Após ter criado o repositório remoto pelo [github](https://github.com) por exemplo, adicione o caminho com o comando `git remote add origin git@github.com:marciellioliveira/Linguagem-C.git`

Depois deixe os arquivos prontos para serem comitados com `git add` com o comando git add é possível adicionar todos arquivos criados de uma vez utilizando um ponto `git add .` ou simplesmente um arquivo de cada vez com `git add arquivo.extensão`

Então já pode comitar os arquivos com `git commit -m 'A mensagem referente ao commit'`
agora seus arquivos já estão no repositório local, quando quiser enviar para o repositório remoto, com o comando `git push -u origin master`

Lembre-se que o `origin` é o nome do alias que você deu ao adicionar o repositório remoto, e `master` quer dizer o branch master em seu repositório.

Para informações mais detalhadas, existe o *Pro Git Book* já traduzido para o português, é gratuito, só consultar.

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/

Uma observação, caso for utilizar ssh, consulte o *Chapter 4* para criar e adicionar ao repositório, o próprio github contém um guia para auxiliar.

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/